# How to show if a language is infinite, then there is no upper bound on the length of words in L?

Tags: complexity-theory, computation-theory

L is a language over a finite alphabet.
How to show that if L is infinite, then there is no upper bound on the length of the words within L?

Can someone help me prove this.

Comment: This question would probably be better suited at math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Try contradiction; what would happen if there is an upper bound ? Image that upper bound is X, then the maximum number of strings is less than S^(X+1) (where S is the number of characters in the alphabet)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is better suited for Computer Science SE!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there is an upper bound = n, on the length of words in L.
Let ∑ be the alphabet.

So number of strings with length 0 = |∑|^0 = 1

number of strings with length 1 = |∑|^1
and so on till
number of strings with length n = |∑|^n

Therefore total number of strings = |∑|^0 + |∑|^1 + … |∑|^n = (|∑|^n  −1)/(|∑|−1) (by geometric progression) which is a finite number since n is finite.

However the language is infinite. Therefore this contradicts our supposition.